# How do you pass the result of a command as an argument for a command?

Tags: macros

I'd like to generate a string and save it for later use. However, it saves the command instead of the string in the following situation:

```
\newcounter{Counter}
\newcommand{\ParentNode} {NULL}
\newcommand{\ThisNode} {Node\theCounter}
\newcommand{\SetParentNode} {\renewcommand{\ParentNode}{\ThisNode}}

Current \textbf{\ThisNode} with parent \textbf{\ParentNode}.\\
\SetParentNode
Current \textbf{\ThisNode} set as parent (\ParentNode).\\
\stepcounter{Counter}
Current \textbf{\ThisNode} with parent \textbf{\ParentNode}.
```

This generates the following output for me:

> Current **Node0** with parent **NULL**. 
>   Current **Node0** set as parent (Node0). 
>   Current **Node1** with parent **Node1**.

This output tells me `\ParentNode` has saved the actual commands and not the string. Something tells me there is a simple solution, but I just can't find it. How do you pass the result of a command instead of the command itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\SetParentNode` macro must have its meaning expanded, so that it remembers actual data and not just macros pointing to data.  So I use an `\edef`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{Counter}
\newcommand{\ParentNode} {NULL}
\newcommand{\ThisNode} {Node\theCounter}
\newcommand{\SetParentNode} {\edef\ParentNode{\ThisNode}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Current \textbf{\ThisNode} with parent \textbf{\ParentNode}.\\
\SetParentNode
Current \textbf{\ThisNode} set as parent (\ParentNode).\\
\stepcounter{Counter}
Current \textbf{\ThisNode} with parent \textbf{\ParentNode}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The OP will have to decide if `\ThisNode` should be similarly expanded *at time of definition* as opposed to the current approach, which expands it, at time of recall.

Answer (score 1):

As long as eTeX-extensions are available, you can probably do it with a macro and `\numexpr` instead of wasting a count-register.

I tried to implement a variant which does without `\edef`, just `\expandafter` and exchanging macro arguments...

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}

\newcommand\nodecounter{-1}%
\newcommand{\ParentNode}{PARENTOFNULL}
\newcommand\ThisNode{NULL}

\newcommand\SetThisNodeAsParentNodeAndSetNewNodeAsThisNode{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\ParentNode\expandafter{\ThisNode}%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\nodecounter\expandafter{\number\numexpr\nodecounter+1\relax}%
  \expandafter\renewcommand
  \expandafter\ThisNode
  \expandafter{\romannumeral0\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\nodecounter}{ Node}}%
}

\begin{document}
\SetThisNodeAsParentNodeAndSetNewNodeAsThisNode
\noindent Current \textbf{\ThisNode} with parent \textbf{\ParentNode}.

\SetThisNodeAsParentNodeAndSetNewNodeAsThisNode
\noindent Current \textbf{\ThisNode} with parent \textbf{\ParentNode}.

\SetThisNodeAsParentNodeAndSetNewNodeAsThisNode
\noindent Current \textbf{\ThisNode} with parent \textbf{\ParentNode}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd define a `\StepNode` command, rather than relying on `\stepcounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{Counter}
\newcommand{\ParentNode}{NULL}
\newcommand{\ThisNode}{}% for safety
\edef\ThisNode{Node\theCounter}% initialize

\newcommand{\SetParentNode}{\let\ParentNode=\ThisNode}

\newcommand{\StepNode}{%
  \stepcounter{Counter}%
  \edef\ThisNode{Node\theCounter}%
}

\begin{document}

Current \textbf{\ThisNode} with parent \textbf{\ParentNode}.

\SetParentNode

Current \textbf{\ThisNode} set as parent (\ParentNode).

\StepNode

Current \textbf{\ThisNode} with parent \textbf{\ParentNode}.

\end{document}
```

[image]